# Insert textbox value to sqlserver table

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, windows

I have a problem with inserting a `TextBox` value into a SqlServer table. I wrote that code, but when I run the form it raises a runtime error: "a network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to sql server". Thanks in advance.

```
public partial class Add_Client : Form
{
    SqlConnection clientConnection;
    string connString;
    SqlCommand insertCommand; 

    public Add_Client()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        connString = "Data Source=.//INSTANCE2;Initial Catalog=Clients;Integrated Security=True";
        clientConnection = new SqlConnection();
        clientConnection.ConnectionString = connString;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand();
            insertCommand.Connection = clientConnection;
            insertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Client_Info values(@Client_Name,@AutorizationNo,@IssueType,@Status)";
            insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Client_Name",SqlDbType.NVarChar,60).Value=txt_Name.Text;
            insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@AutorizationNo", SqlDbType.Int, 60).Value =txt_Auth.Text.ToString();
            insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Issue", SqlDbType.Text, 200).Value =txt_Iss.Text;
            insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Status", SqlDbType.TexT, 15).Value=txt_sta.TexT;
            insertCommand.Connection.Open();
            insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (clientConnection != null)
            {
                clientConnection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like either your connection string is wrong or that SQL Server isn't up.

Comment: A quick pointer with the exception handling. If you are simply going to bubble the `Exception` back up to the calling code, you don't need your `catch` part of the `try-catch-finally` statement.

Comment: Also correct your parameter names, they cant have spaces. Change `@Date To Memorize` to `@DateToMemorize` or `@Date_To_Memorize`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the .// in the host name in your connection string shouldn't be there.  i wouldn't expect it to work.  you should just have the machine name itself there.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your connecting string, u may find it usefull:

http://www.connectionstrings.com/

If you are sure about the connection string then please check your database status.

Comment: You sure? It's usually ServerName\InstanceName I would have expected .\\INstance2

Comment: ok , the connection string wasn't ok , i corrected it , now when i turned to insert textbox values to the table another runtime error apperas which is Unable to open the physical file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQLServer\MSSQL10_50.INSTANCE2\MSSQL\DATA\pubs.mdf". Operating system error 32: "32(The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.)".
Unable to open the physical file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.INSTANCE2\MSSQL\DATA\pubs_log.LDF".

Comment: What is your database? Did you installed 2 or more sql instance like sql 2008 express and 2005? If so, please make sure the SQL Server Express 2008 instance name and connect to it in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio or vice versa. Another thing is u may not have the privilige to the folder that this database in. Please let us know.

Comment: i have 2 instance for SQL Server Express 2008 r2, but i already named INSTANCE2 in the connection string ! how can i know that i have a privilage to that folder?

Comment: Code Snippet
 
declare @sqlser varchar(20) 
 
EXEC master..xp_regread @rootkey='HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', @key='SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\MSSQLSERVER', 
 
@value_name='objectname', @value=@sqlser OUTPUT
 
PRINT 'Account Starting SQL Server Service:' +convert(varchar(30),@sqlser)

Comment: @kemel Can Kara ,What is that ?

Answer (score 0):

The parameter names in SQL should not contain blanks. I you want to use blanks you have to enclose the parameter name in square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

Is your connection string correct? That basically means it couldn't connect to the server.

Also, just a tip - I wouldn't do this:

```
 insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@Autorization No", SqlDbType.Int, 60).Value =txt_Auth.Text.ToString();
```

...

Its just asking for trouble. Instead copy it, sanitize it and make sure that it won't cause an exception.

Comment: for carification:the table in sqlserver consists of 3 columns named (Client_Name,Autorization No,Issue)

Comment: I also wouldnt...`@Autorization No` - parameter with space? :)

Comment: I woudln't have spaces in my column names in the table either, they are a PIA.